# How to clear contents of dynoTable new row

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

I'm working with the Dyno Table jQuery plugin, and every time I add a new row, it copies the content from the last row...

I'm trying to work out how to add a new row, but enforce that all content is empty, any ideas greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to the actual plugin:
http://www.seomoves.org/demos/dynotable-demo/

```
/* 
 *  jquery.dynotable.js
 *  Created on Aug 1, 2011 3:36:39 PM by bob
 */
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        dynoTable: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                removeClass: '.row-remover',
                cloneClass: '.row-cloner',
                addRowTemplateId: '#add-template',
                addRowButtonId: '#add-row',
                lastRowRemovable: true,
                orderable: true,
                dragHandleClass: ".drag-handle",
                insertFadeSpeed: "slow",
                removeFadeSpeed: "fast",
                hideTableOnEmpty: true,
                onRowRemove: function(){},
                onRowClone: function(){},
                onRowAdd: function(){},
                onTableEmpty: function(){},
                onRowReorder: function(){}
            };     

            options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            var cloneRow = function(btn) {
                var clonedRow = $(btn).closest('tr').clone();  
                var tbod = $(btn).closest('tbody');
                insertRow(clonedRow, tbod); 
                options.onRowClone();
            }

            var insertRow = function(clonedRow, tbod) {                
                var numRows = $(tbod).children("tr").length;
                if(options.hideTableOnEmpty && numRows == 0) {
                    $(tbod).parents("table").first().show();
                }

                $(clonedRow).find('*').andSelf().filter('[id]').each( function() {
                    //change to something else so we don't have ids with the same name
                    this.id += '__c';
                });

                //finally append new row to end of table                           
                $(tbod).append( clonedRow );
                bindActions(clonedRow);
                $(tbod).children("tr:last").hide().fadeIn(options.insertFadeSpeed);
            }

            var removeRow = function(btn) {
                var tbod = $(btn).parents("tbody:first");
                var numRows = $(tbod).children("tr").length;

                if(numRows > 1 || options.lastRowRemovable === true) {
                    var trToRemove = $(btn).parents("tr:first");
                    $(trToRemove).fadeOut(options.removeFadeSpeed, function() {
                        $(trToRemove).remove();
                        options.onRowRemove();
                        if(numRows == 1) {                            
                            if(options.hideTableOnEmpty) {
                                $(tbod).parents('table').first().hide();
                            }
                            options.onTableEmpty();
                        }
                    });
                }                            
            }

            var bindClick = function(elem, fn) {
                $(elem).click(fn);                
            }                  

            var bindCloneLink = function(lnk) {
                bindClick(lnk, function(){                                
                    var btn = $(this);
                    cloneRow(btn); 
                    return false;
                });
            }

            var bindRemoveLink = function(lnk) {
                bindClick(lnk, function(){ 
                    var btn = $(this);
                    removeRow(btn);
                    return false;
                });
            }

            var bindActions = function(obj) {              
                obj.find(options.removeClass).each(function() {
                    bindRemoveLink($(this));
                });

                obj.find(options.cloneClass).each(function() {
                    bindCloneLink($(this));
                });
            }

            return this.each(function() {                             
                //Sanity check to make sure we are dealing with a single case
                if(this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'table') {                                
                    var table = $(this);
                    var tbody = $(table).children("tbody").first();

                    if(options.orderable && jQuery().sortable) {                        
                        $(tbody).sortable({
                            handle : options.dragHandleClass,
                            helper:  function(e, ui) {
                                ui.children().each(function() {
                                    $(this).width($(this).width());
                                });
                                return ui;
                            },
                            items: "tr",
                            update : function (event, ui) {
                                options.onRowReorder();
                            }
                        });
                    }                                 

                    $(table).find(options.addRowTemplateId).each(function(){
                        $(this).removeAttr("id");
                        var tmpl = $(this);
                        tmpl.remove();                        
                        bindClick($(options.addRowButtonId), function(){ 
                            var newTr = tmpl.clone();
                            insertRow(newTr, tbody);
                            options.onRowAdd();
                            return false;
                        });
                    });                                
                    bindActions(table);

                    var numRows = $(tbody).children("tr").length;
                    if(options.hideTableOnEmpty && numRows == 0) {
                        $(table).hide();
                    }
                }                 
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `insertRow` method to this:

```
var insertRow = function (clonedRow, tbod) {
    var numRows = $(tbod).children("tr").length;
    if (options.hideTableOnEmpty && numRows == 0) {
        $(tbod).parents("table").first().show();
    }

    $(clonedRow).find('*').andSelf().filter('[id]').each(function () {
        //change to something else so we don't have ids with the same name
        this.id += '__c';
    });
    $(clonedRow).children().each(function () {
        $(this).html() = '';
    });

    //finally append new row to end of table                           
    $(tbod).append(clonedRow);
    bindActions(clonedRow);
    $(tbod).children("tr:last").hide().fadeIn(options.insertFadeSpeed);
}
```

**Disclaimer: Untested code.**